# Backoffice : How to filter Date entries based on Year using referenceSearchCondition in Create/Editor Wizard

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

**SAP Commerce 1811**

We have a model like this ..

**HolidayCalendar** has an attribute Year of Integer type and collection of Holiday Calendar Entries.
**HolidayCalendarEntry** has attribute Date

In Backoffice -> Create/Editor Wizard, i want to apply **referenceSearchCondition** filter on HolidayCalendar:Entries attribute so that whenever i choose existing entries in Holiday Calendar i can get only those entries fall under associated year.

e.g. I created new Holiday Calendar of 2021, then i can see only those entries which has date of 2021.

So far I tried something with Dynamic Form but its not working

```
     <context type="HolidayCalendar" component="editorAreaDynamicForms" merge-by="module">
    <df:dynamicForms xmlns:df="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/component/dynamicForms">
        <df:attribute id="dynamicFormsEntryFiltering1" paramName="referenceSearchCondition_date_greaterOrEquals" disabledIf="date==null" computedValue="T(com.hybris.util.DateUtils).getFirstDay(parentObject.year)" qualifier="entries" triggeredOn="date"/>
    </df:dynamicForms>
    </context>

   <context type="HolidayCalendar" component="editorAreaDynamicForms" merge-by="module">
    <df:dynamicForms xmlns:df="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/component/dynamicForms">
        <df:attribute id="dynamicFormsEntryFiltering2" paramName="referenceSearchCondition_date_lessOrEquals" disabledIf="date==null" computedValue="T(com.hybris.util.DateUtils).getLastDay(parentObject.year)" qualifier="entries" triggeredOn="date"/>
    </df:dynamicForms>
   </context>
```

Here I am trying to set a range of FirstDay and LastDay of Holiday Calendar Year and match entries date fall under it. But it's not working.

Any other suggestion how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom editor for "entries" attribute,

```
public class EntriesEditor<T> extends DefaultMultiReferenceEditor<T>
```

Override the method and add your filter condition within this method

1. updateReferencesListBoxModel

Reference this custom editor in your config.xml,

<wz:property qualifier="entries" editor="com.backoffice.editors.entrieseditor" />